# How to convert BLOB into PDF file in the Node environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, blob

I have a Node Js server, in it, I am fetching a blob data from another web service (which is for a PDF file), now after receiving blob, I want to convert it again into PDF file.

Anyone, who knows how to achieve this please help.

Here is my code block I have tried so far:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Blob = require('fetch-blob');
const fs = require('fs');

fetch(url, options)
   .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      res.blob().then(async (data) => {

         const result = data.stream();
         // below line of code saves a blank pdf file
         fs.createWriteStream(objectId + '.pdf').write(result);
      })
   })
   .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- For `fs.createWriteStream(objectId + '.pdf').write(data)`, please modify `res.blob()` to `res.buffer()`.
- Please modify `.then(res => {res.blob().then()` to `.then(res => res.buffer()).then(`.

#### Modified script:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => res.buffer())
  .then(data => {
    fs.createWriteStream(objectId + '.pdf').write(data);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the fetch process using `url` and `options` works fine.

#### References:

- [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch)
- [write()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

Comment: @Mayank yaduvanshi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.